# How to append an element loaded via ajax to another previously loaded via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How can I add an HTML element received via AJAX to another HTML element previously added via AJAX? I tried to use `.append` but not working:

#### Example:

```
$.ajax({ (...), success: function() { $('.padding').append('<div id="request">Foo</div>') } });
```

This above working well, because `.padding` is initially loaded on the page. But when I try

```
$.ajax({ (...), success: function(data) { $('#request').append('<div class="description">Bar</div>') } });
```

not working. Why and how can I do it the right way?

Below, my `.padding` content:

```
<div class="padding">
    <!-- Below, HTML result from first AJAX  -->    
    <div class="ui attached segments" id="request"> 
        <div class="ui right center aligned segment" id="header"> 
            <h4 class="ui gray header"> P2017003</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="ui stackable three item menu segment">
            <div style="justify-content: flex-start" class="item">
                <button class="ui button">
                    <i class="left chevron icon"></i>
                    Voltar
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!--Buttons AJAX-->
                <div class="two ui red inverted small buttons segment-controller">
                    <button id="detalhes" class="ui active button">
                        Detalhes
                    </button>
                    <button id="acompanhar" class="ui button">
                        Acompanhar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="justify-content: flex-end" class="item">
                <button class="ui button">Imprimir</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui main segment">
            P-2017-003
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're sure the second request completes after the first request has been completed?

Comment: @Thijs I was wondering that, but didn't dare to ask...!

Comment: @Thijs Yes, the second requisition is only made after the first.

Comment: My second ajax is made only when the first is finalized. The first ajax load a request div tag that contains a button to run the second ajax. My problem is append the response HTML to the request div tag previously loaded by the first ajax.

Comment: Can you add the HTML of the `div.padding` at the time the second call is made? What you're trying to do shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Thijs Added in question

Comment: I've tried it with your provided HTML and I still can't reproduce it. I did notice that none of your `button` elements have the attribute `type="button"` which means all of them are submit buttons. Perhaps there is something else in your site that is interfering with this?

Answer (score 2):

I've rigged up this setup to simulate your situation. I've never once encountered the situation where the div with id `request` is not present in the DOM.

```js
function getDataA() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
  }).then(result => {
    $('.padding').append('<div id="request">Call A finished</div>');
  });
}

function getDataB() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2'
  }).then(result => {
    if ($('#request').length === 0) {
      console.log('no request element found');
    }
    $('#request').append('<div class="description">Call B finished</div>');
  });
}

getDataA()
  .then(getDataB);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="padding"></div>
```

My guess is your second call is done before the first call. Perhaps your code is something like this:

```
getDataA();
getDataB();
```

Now you're depending on which call finishes first. When call B finishes first your code breaks and when call A finishes first you're in luck.

You could run both requests in parallel if you want, it will require using `$.when()`.

```js
function getDataA() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
  });
}

function getDataB() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2'
  });
}

$.when(getDataA(), getDataB())
  .then(function(resultA, resultB) {
    $('.padding').append('<div id="request">Call A finished</div>');
    $('#request').append('<div class="description">Call B finished</div>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="padding"></div>
```

I've tried it with your provided HTML and I still am not able to reproduce the situation.

```js
function getDataA() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
  }).then(result => {
    $('.padding').append(`
        <!-- Below, HTML result from first AJAX  -->    
    <div class="ui attached segments" id="request"> 
        <div class="ui right center aligned segment" id="header"> 
            <h4 class="ui gray header"> P2017003</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="ui stackable three item menu segment">
            <div style="justify-content: flex-start" class="item">
                <button class="ui button">
                    <i class="left chevron icon"></i>
                    Voltar
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!--Buttons AJAX-->
                <div class="two ui red inverted small buttons segment-controller">
                    <button id="detalhes" class="ui active button">
                        Detalhes
                    </button>
                    <button id="acompanhar" class="ui button">
                        Acompanhar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="justify-content: flex-end" class="item">
                <button class="ui button">Imprimir</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui main segment">
            P-2017-003
        </div>
    </div>
    `);
    const
      trigger = document.getElementById('detalhes');
    trigger.addEventListener('click', getDataB);
  });
}


function getDataB() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2'
  }).then(result => {
    if ($('#request').length === 0) {
      console.log('no request element found');
    }
    $('#request').append('<div class="description">Call B finished</div>');
  });
}


const
  trigger = document.getElementById('fill-padding');
trigger.addEventListener('click', getDataA);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fill-padding" type="button">Fill padding</button>
<div class="padding">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. And thank you for you response. But I just needed to use the id and class attributes for select a element. Before, I only used the class attribute (.padding). I don't know why, but only work after I used both.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is that jQuery hasn't update it's internal structures yet.

Sometimes this happens when appending elements, and trying to find them right away.

Instead do one of the 3:

1. Use jQuery.find() instead (eg: $("body").find("#id"))
2. Store the element html as a jQuery object:

   var html = 'Hi';
   var elem = $(html);
3. "Accumulate' the html all at once, and append it all at once.

   var html = '';
   $.ajax({ (...), success: function() { 
           html += 'Foo'; 
           $.ajax({ (...), success: function(data) { 
                   html += 'Bar';
                   $('.padding').append(html);
               } 
           });
       } 
   });

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: I don't have a written account, but I know that appending elements in an ajax call (an asynchronous non-ui bound process) can be troublesome and fetching them after being appended doesn't always work, and I have to resort to the above.